# .Net console app - call a specific service if there are multiple services

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create a .Net console app which is for user management including create user, reset user password, and edit user role. Therefore, my app has three separate methods in `UserCreationService`. I wonder if I can call a specific method whenever I want from the command line? For example, I want to create user I just type in command line: `donet run {connectionString} {username} {password} {rolename}`, but sometimes I may want to change user role, I will type `dotnet run {connectionString} {username} {roleName} {newRoleName}`. So is it possible to implement this system?

My code so far in Program.cs:

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string connectionString = null;
      string username = null;
      string password = null;
      string roleName = null;
      string newRoleName = null;

      try
      {
        if (args.Length < 3)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("This app requires at least 3 arguments");
          Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
          connectionString = args[0];
          username = args[1];
          password = args[2];
          roleName = args[3];
          newRoleName = args[4];
        }

        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        //setup our DI
        // Add framework services.            
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
          options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        });

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddScoped<IUserCreationService, UserCreationService>();

        // Build the IoC from the service collection
        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        var userService = provider.GetService<IUserCreationService>();

        // Create User
        userService.CreateUser(username, password, roleName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // Chang user role
        userService.EditRole(username, roleName, newRoleName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // Reset user password
        userService.ResetPassword(username, password).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        Console.ReadKey();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        System.Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION: " + e.Message);
        System.Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        if (e.InnerException != null)
        {
          System.Console.WriteLine("INNER EXCEPTION: " + e.InnerException.Message);
          System.Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.StackTrace);
        }
      }

      System.Console.WriteLine();
      Environment.Exit(1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You should look into command line argument parser libraries, which make it easy to specify which piece of data a value represents.

Comment: @mason can you provide me some references?

Comment: Why don't you try doing a web search to find a library?

Answer (score 1):

Could you just require the user to type in a password in both cases? That way, all you have to do is check if args[4] contains anything. If it does, edit the user. Otherwise, create a new user.

Comment: Thank you, that could be a hacky way for now, but my app may grow up and would demand more services, I have to find a solid way.